# Error when launch yarn run encore dev for the first time

Tags: symfony, yarnpkg, webpack-encore

I've a problem when I configure for the first time the webpack.config.js in my Symfony 3.4 project.
I folow the documentation of symfony to install and configure encore but I don't know why I've allways this error:

```
$ yarn run encore dev
yarn run v1.6.0
$ [my_root_project_path]\node_modules\.bin\encore dev
Running webpack ...
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors10:01:31
 error
Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'web/build/app.js' in '[my_root_project_path]'
error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

my webpack.config.js file is this:

```
// webpack.config.js
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');
Encore
 .setOutputPath('web/build/')
 .setPublicPath('/build')
 .addEntry('app', 'web/build/app.js')
 .autoProvidejQuery()
 .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
 .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
;
module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

Does the problem come from a permission on files that Encore doesn't? Anyway, I'm lost, I don't know what to do.

Config:

- Windows 10
- wamp server
- php version 5.6.31
- Symfony 3.4
- yarn 1.6.0

*Note:
I know there is probably another post of the same kind of issue but I think that at the moment I have tested everything and my problem persists. I'm always listening and if you think there's a stackoverflow post that can solve my problem I'll let you share it with me.*

Comment: of course i continue to prospect on the internet to find a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in addEntry path

`.addEntry('app', 'web/build/app.js')`

which does not point to the right file. The correct syntax is:

```
.addEntry(<name_of_the_entry>, <path_to_the_entry>)
```

where path_to_the_entry must point to a js file you want to add in your build, not directly to your build path. This file should be in a different folder e.g. 'your_project_root/assets/js/your_js_file.js' as specified in doc.

Encore will create the appropriate .js file (and possibly .css if you added one in your .js file) in your web/build folder so that your users can access those files.